# Is there a BSONDocumentWriter and BSONDocumentReader for JsValue?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-json

Im trying to write a case class to BSONCollection, but i cannot find any Reads and Writes to JsValue.
Is there a BSONDocumentWriter and BSONDocumentReader for JsValue?
Oh any suggesting for how to write one?
this is my case class:
Rule:

```
case class Rule(_id: BSONObjectID,
                metadata: Metadata,
                conditions: List[Condition])
```

Metadata:

```
case class Metadata(
                     name: String,
                     description: String,
                     active: Boolean,
      // Optional:
                     refId: Option[BSONObjectID], 
                     keys: Option[List[Key]],
                     createdAt: Option[Instant],
                     lastVersionExists: Option[String],
                     data: Option[JsValue],
                     externalId: Option[String] 
                   )
```

Condition:

```
case class Condition(name: String,
                     `type`: LogicType,
                     data: JsValue)
```

and writes and reads:

```
implicit object BSONInstantHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONDateTime, Instant] {
    def read(bson: BSONDateTime): Instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(bson.value)
    def write(date: Instant) = BSONDateTime(date.toEpochMilli)
  }

  object LogicTypeReader extends BSONReader[BSONString, LogicType] {
    override def read(bson: BSONString): LogicType = LogicType.namesToValuesMap(bson.value)
  }

  object LogicTypeWriter extends BSONWriter[LogicType, BSONString] {
    override def write(t: LogicType): BSONString = BSONString(t.entryName)
  }

  // Reads
  implicit def LogicTypeReads: BSONReader[BSONString, LogicType] = LogicTypeReads
  implicit val MetadataReader: BSONDocumentReader[Metadata] = Macros.reader[Metadata]
  implicit val KeyReader: BSONDocumentReader[Key] = Macros.reader[Key]
  implicit val ConditionReader: BSONDocumentReader[Condition] = Macros.reader[Condition]
  implicit val RuleReader: BSONDocumentReader[Rule] = Macros.reader[Rule]

  // Writes
  implicit def LogicTypeWrites: BSONWriter[LogicType, BSONString] = LogicTypeWrites
  implicit val MetadataWrites: BSONDocumentWriter[Metadata] = Macros.writer[Metadata]
  implicit val KeyWrites: BSONDocumentWriter[Key] = Macros.writer[Key]
  implicit val ConditionWrites: BSONDocumentWriter[Condition] = Macros.writer[Condition]
  implicit val RuleWrites: BSONDocumentWriter[Rule] = Macros.writer[Rule]
```

Thanks!

Comment: To get helped, it's recommended to indicate the versions (and read the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/json/overview.html)). Also using BSON values in case classes (or other model type) is not recommended (as coupling it with the DB).

Comment: Thanks!
as  i see from the documentation, its solving the following exception:
```Implicit not found for '..': reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONReader[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
```
but I'm using: 
```Implicit not found for 'data': reactivemongo.bson.BSONReader[play.api.libs.json.JsValue, _]
```
(Without the .API), any suggesting?
Thanks! @cchantep

Comment: Once again, you indicate no version. Also narrow your question according the question (guess about `Condition`)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I updated the comment and forgot to indicate the version
Im using ```"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.18.8-play27"`` for reactive mongo and play: ```"com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.2"```
About the question, i cant make writers and readers for data at Metadata case class and also for data in Condition
Thanks! @cchantep

Comment: 0.18 is (too) old

Comment: @cchantep I tried to change to bsoncollection but got some problems, maybe you know how to assists to fix without transfer the whole project to BSONCollection?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316206/transactions-with-jsoncollection-instead-of-bsoncollection
thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.18.8-play27",
```

```
import reactivemongo.play.json.BSONFormats
import scala.language.implicitConversions

  implicit object JsValueHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONValue, JsValue] {
    implicit override def read(bson: BSONValue): JsValue = BSONFormats.toJSON(bson)
    implicit override def write(j: JsValue): BSONValue = BSONFormats.toBSON(j).get
  }
```